# Unity UI Toolkit doesn't match the game

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, ui-toolkit

After a couple of days struggling with UI Toolkit i just dont know what to do.
My problem:
I have a scene, camera and a gameview from simulator that doesnt match UIDocument
Look like this:
[image: View from UIBuilder + Game]
[image: Visual Element settings]
[image: Button settings]

But gameview:
[image: GameView]
If I build the UI to look from the "Game", then when I build the project everything will just break?

[image: My]
[image: My]
[image: My]

I originally wanted my UI to adjust to the size of the specific device, but it doesn't.
I tried to figure it out on my own, I tweaked the camera settings, the settings panel, tried to change the elements settings (I set the pixel format, percentages, also absolute positioning and relative), but none of this gave me the desired result at all.
I tried to look in the documentation, some videos on youtube, just tried to look for a similar problem on the internet, but it did not help to solve the problem. Also, I tried unity demo project "King crushers", which works exactly as I want it in my project, only I did not understand how it is designed, it is not like CSS in the web.

In the end I am left with no idea what to do, UIBuilder just does not work.
Am I missing some basic concepts?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience,

- Open UI Document's UI_Panel
- Change the scale mode. (my case -> "constant pixel size")

I hope it will work.